# CodeIgniter foreign character issue within function names

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm working on a turkish project and there are normal function calls like this for example:

```
$this->model_board->Board_Column_Info();
```

The capital "i" in the code above spits out following error code:

```
 [07-Apr-2014 08:11:22 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Model_board::Board_Column_Info() in /home/project/public_html/application/controllers/main.php on line 6396
```

if you run the same code with a lowercase "i" **it works without any issues**.

```
$this->model_board->Board_Column_info();
```

Although it's not related to the question, I'll post the code to the function too:

```
function Board_Column_Info ( $board_column_id )
{

    $this->db->select('*');

    $this->db->from('board_column');

    $this->db->where('board_column_id', $board_column_id );


    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Maybe it's interfering with the turkish character of "ı".

```
i I lowercase and uppercase i
ı I lowercase and uppsercase ı
```

it does only happen in one project so I'm confused and don't know how to approach this.

I'm suspecting a encoding error, how can I check that?

Comment: What exactly you want to check ?

Comment: show the method Board_Column_Info()

Comment: @amirbawab why it throws this error. The function is in place but I still get the error.

Comment: @sunny, although it's unrelated, I've posted you the example code

Comment: interesting, i guess my answer fails!

Comment: So when you type I on the keyboard it shows different character ?

Comment: @amirbawab no it's the same. Only the lowercase i will spit out as ı but I have different keys for that so I can press both of them. I've also tried to capitalize the "i" in the function call with the editors (sublime) uppercase function, thinking that my keyboard may give me the wrong char but it didn't help either.

Comment: Try to copy the i from this website, so you can make sure that the ASCII is the same.

Comment: @amirbawab didn't work either. Still the same.

Comment: Therefore there must be something in the function, can you post the code ?

Comment: @amirbawab the code is in the question, updated it a couple of minutes ago but, if you look closely at the error messages it tell us that it cannot find a function that is declared under that name and not that there is an error in the function.

Comment: If you are on windows try ALT + 73 for the I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
```

Using this little (insane) code messes with all of your routine and function names.

Suddenly a function name Info() will not work anymore, you'll have to call it as info() because capital i will be regarded as capital turkish ı (looks the exact same when written in capital).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it doesnt have to do anything with turkish characters, it s actually by the name your method is defined, m sure your method `Board_Column_info()` is defined with lowercase 'i', the method names are casesensitive i.e. they have to be called in the same case in which they are declared, if you want to check try changing your function declaration to `Board_Column_Info()`  , then it will throw fatal error for lowercase 'i'.

Comment: Well it's the exact opposite case. The method is defines as "Board_Column_Info" and it should work when called like this. Although method names are in fact not case sensitive. It doesn't throw and an error when I declare it as Board_Column_info and call it like Board_Column_Info. I suspect the capital "i" as the culprit here but don't know how to debug it. It should work both ways, shouldn't it?

Comment: i get it! i guess you are right, its a very weird behaviour!